# Multithreaded C++ Program Not Running In Parallel Using vector<thread> and .join()

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, thread-synchronization

**Note:** This is the first post I have made on this site, but I have searched extensively and was not able to find a solution to my problem.
I have written a program which essentially tests all permutations of a vector of numbers to find an optimal sequence as defined by me. Of course, computing permutations of numbers is very time consuming even for small inputs, so I am trying to speed things up by using multithreading.

---

Here is a small sample which replicates the problem:

```
class TaskObject {
public:
    void operator()() {
        recursiveFunc();
    }
private:
    Solution *bestSolution; //Shared by every TaskObject, but can only be accessed by one at a time
    void recursiveFunc() {
        if (base_case) { 
            //Only part where shared object is accessed
            //base_case is rarely reached
            return;
        }
        recursiveFunc();
    }
};

void runSolutionWithThreads() {
    vector<thread> threads(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());
    vector<TaskObject> tasks_vector(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());
    updateTasks(); //Sets parameters that intialize the first call to recursiveFunc
    for (int q = 0; q < (int)tasks_vector.size(); ++q) {
        threads[q] = std::thread(tasks_vector[q]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)threads.size(); ++i) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
}
```

I imagined that this would enable all threads to run in parallel, but I can see using the performance profiler in visual studio and in the advanced settings of windows task manager that only 1 thread is running at a time. On a system with access to 4 threads, the CPU gets bounded at 25%. *I get correct output every time I run, so there are no issues with the algorithm logic. Work is spread out as evenly as possible among all task objects. Collisions with shared data rarely occur. Program implementation with thread pool always ran at nearly 100%.*

The objects submitted to the threads don't print to cout and all have their own copies of the data required to perform their work except for one shared object they all reference by pointer.

```
private:
    Solution* bestSolution;
```

This shared data is not susceptible to a data race condition since I used lock_guard from mutex to make it so only one thread can update bestSolution at a time.

**In other words, why isn't my CPU running at nearly 100% for my multithreaded program which uses as many threads as there are available in the system?**

I can readily update this post with more information if needed.

Comment: You probably need a [mcve], and your shared object looks highly suspicious of being a data race

Comment: @PasserBy The shared object should not be susceptible to a data race condition.

Comment: The code isn't complete just yet, the rule of thumb is that someone should be able to copy-paste something and see your results. That is not to say you should stuff everything in here, it means you should mock `Solution` and its access in some way that can still replicate the problem. If you later realized the problem is tied to the way `Solution` works, you probably solved the problem anyways.

Answer (score 2):

In debugging your application, use the debugger to "break all" threads.   Then examine each thread with the debug thread window to see where each thread is executing.   Likely you will find that only one thread is executing code, while the rest are all blocked on the mutex that the one running thread is holding.

If you show a more complete example of the code it can greatly assist.

Comment: I updated the post to note that the collisions with the shared data rarely occur. In the debugger it seems as though all threads are doing work at about the same pace, but on my system of 4 threads the CPU is bounded at 25% utilization in the performance profiler. I know there is definitely an error with this, because when I ran the program using a thread pool implementation I found the program was almost always at 100% CPU utilization.